# WebView can't call JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have tried everything and still doesn't work, please help:

I setup my WebView here:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private MyWebViewClient mWebViewClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient(context);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mWebViewClient, "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

This is where I call my function from JS:

```
    <script>
            $("#logInButton").click(function(){
                if(isAndroid){
                    Android.onJavaLogIn();
                }
                return false;
            });
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Log In" id="logInButton" />
```

Here is how I handle it:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
    private MainActivity context;

    public MyWebViewClient(MainActivity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onJavaLogIn(){
        context.onMainLogIn();
    }

}
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public void onMainLogIn(){
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onJSLogIn();");
    }
}
```

This is the JS function it's suppose to call:

```
    <script>
        function onJSLogIn(){
            $("#logInButton").hide();
            $("#logOutButton").show();
        }
    </script>
```

The entire chain seem to be correct, and I verify via debug that onMainLogIn() in MainActivity does get called, but the JS function onJSLogIn() never get called, why?

Comment: I wonder what is "isAndroid" in Java Script. How you set it up? Did you try removing "if (isAndroid)"?

Comment: IsAndroid definitely isn't the problem because onMainLogIn is called successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out WebView only work on the main UI thread.  So I had to warp the call function like this:

```
public void onMainLogIn(){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onJSLogIn();");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here everything looks fine. Since we can't debug it, we can only suggest few things.
 1. First write one alert in onJSLogIn JS method to make sure function not getting called.Because logInButton, logOutButton dom elements might not have loaded.
 2. Connect your webview to remote debug and check for errors using chrome ADB tool.

Comment: It seem like LoadURL isn't working on subsequent call, any idea as to why?